# how to create the dynamic form fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, django-forms, javascript-objects

i want to create a dynamic form  like the user needs to add attribute but those attribute not defined previously he can add as many he can for example he created a dress he want to add attribute like size he will click on add attribuute that will generate an html i have did this but there i need to insert some variable so i can change the name of the attributes

```
var i =1;
function add_fields() {
    var emptydiv = document.createElement('div')
    emptydiv.innerHTML = '<div class="col-12 col-md-6"><div class="group"><input type="text" name="`{i}`" id="Royalties" required><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span><label>Attributes</label></div></div><div class="col-12 col-md-6"><div class="group"><input type="text" name="Size" id="Size" required><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span><label>value</label></div></div></div>'
    document.getElementById('addable').appendChild(emptydiv);
    i++;
    console.log(i)
    return emptydiv;     
    // console.log("Hello world")                   
}
```

what i want to change the name fields in this html by the variable i

Comment: There's no such thing. Either you find the element(e.g getElementById, querySelector, ...) and change the attribute or completely replace it. note: id should be unique per document (id="Royalties" add numbers to it or use classes instead).
But if you want to render HTML from a string just use template literal instead of regular single quote. like `var a = \`<input name="${somevar}">\``

Comment: can you tell what exact i  need to do to solve this issue

Comment: thank yo u brother now my code is working

Comment: you can answer now i will vote it

Comment: Just added fixed version of your snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish.

I changed regular single quotes into a template literal

```js
var i =1;
function add_fields() {
    var emptydiv = document.createElement('div')
    emptydiv.innerHTML = `<div class="col-12 col-md-6"><div class="group"><input type="text" name="${i}" required><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span><label>Attributes</label></div></div><div class="col-12 col-md-6"><div class="group"><input type="text" name="Size" id="Size" required><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span><label>value</label></div></div></div>`
    document.getElementById('addable').appendChild(emptydiv);
    i++;
    console.log(i)
    return emptydiv;     
    // console.log("Hello world")                   
}

add_fields();
```

```html
<div id="addable"></div>
```